# Tomcat hangs on the APR Connector (SSL) init

Tags: tomcat, ssl, tomcat7, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to configure the Apache Tomcat to use the native APR connector with SSL. I have a certificate signed by an certificate authority. This certificate is PEM encoded.

But the Tomcat hangs on the APR connection initialization.

Here is my server.xml:

```
<Connector port="80" 
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" 
           compression="on" />

<Connector port="8443"
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" 
           secure="true" 
           SSLEnabled="true"
           SSLCertificateFile="D:\certificates\myCertificate.crt"
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="D:\certificates\myCertificatePrivateKey.crt"
           SSLPassword="myPassword"
           SSLVerifyClient="false"/>

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Tomcat's log file:

```
2015-01-27 18:10:13 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 3 2014 08:39:16 UTC
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.57.0
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows Server 2012
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.2
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JAVA_HOME:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_25-b18
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\Q-DAS\chy.stat\tomcat
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\Q-DAS\chy.stat\tomcat
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dsmartstat.home=D:\Q-DAS\chy.stat
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\Q-DAS\chy.stat\tomcat
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\Q-DAS\chy.stat\tomcat
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Q-DAS\chy.stat\tomcat\endorsed
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Q-DAS\chy.stat\tomcat\temp
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=D:\Q-DAS\chy.stat\tomcat\conf\logging.properties
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:HeapDumpPath=D:\Q-DAS\chy.stat\heapDumps
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=20001
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: exit
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Xms128m
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Xmx1024m
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.32 using APR version 1.5.1.
Led 27, 2015 6:10:14 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Led 27, 2015 6:10:15 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014)
Led 27, 2015 6:10:15 ODP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-80"]
Led 27, 2015 6:10:15 ODP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8443"]
```

Here is the thread dump:

```
Attaching to process ID 5324, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.25-b02
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread 19: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run() @bci=51 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 17: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(int, java.net.InetSocketAddress[]) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=37 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=7 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=42 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(java.net.Socket) @bci=60 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.ServerSocket.accept() @bci=48 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept() @bci=1 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop() @bci=55 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run() @bci=1 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 16: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(int, java.net.InetSocketAddress[]) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=37 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=7 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=42 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(java.net.Socket) @bci=60 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.ServerSocket.accept() @bci=48 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop() @bci=55 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run() @bci=1 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(int, java.net.InetSocketAddress[]) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=37 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=7 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=42 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(java.net.Socket) @bci=60 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.ServerSocket.accept() @bci=48 (Interpreted frame)
 - javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept() @bci=1 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop() @bci=55 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run() @bci=1 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 11: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 10: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 9: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=44 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run() @bci=36 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 8: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run() @bci=36 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 4: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSLContext.setCertificate(long, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind() @bci=894, line=586 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init() @bci=8, line=646 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init() @bci=274, line=434 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal() @bci=94, line=978 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init() @bci=29, line=102 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal() @bci=105, line=559 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init() @bci=29, line=102 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal() @bci=212, line=821 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init() @bci=29, line=102 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load() @bci=573, line=638 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(java.lang.String[]) @bci=9, line=663 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=100 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=6 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=56 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(java.lang.String[]) @bci=104, line=280 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(java.lang.String[]) @bci=144, line=454 (Interpreted frame)
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked that your private key doesn't need a password ?
I've just got this problem today.
I removed the password with OpenSSL: `openssl rsa -in privateKey.pem -out newPrivateKey.pem`